# SKColor comparison works in simulator not on iPhone 5s, and with standard colors not custom ones

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

The following code fails on an iPhone 5s, meaning it reaches the else case, but works fine in the simulator. It also works fine if we use standard colors for red and blue (i.e., SKColor.blueColor(), SKColor.redColor())

```
    let BlueColor = SKColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 185/255.0, blue: 252/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let RedColor = SKColor(red: 250/255.0, green: 50/255.0, blue: 53/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let dot = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dot50")

    dot.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
    dot.color = BlueColor

    if (dot.color == BlueColor) {
        println("Blue!")
    } else if (dot.color == RedColor) {
        println("Red!")
    } else {
        println("Nooooo! This shouldn't happen")
    }
```

Any clues why?

Comment: shot in the dark: have you double checked simulator isnt running diff version of ios compared to your device?

Comment: It seems the issue is related to the precision of CGFloats, causing two SKColors not to be treated as equal even though they are conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you need to identify these nodes by their color? Perhaps you could do something like this...

```
let BlueColor = SKColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 185/255.0, blue: 252/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let RedColor = SKColor(red: 250/255.0, green: 50/255.0, blue: 53/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let dot = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dot50")

dot.colorBlendFactor = 1.0
dot.color = BlueColor
dot.name = "BlueNode"

if (dot.name == "BlueNode") {
    foundBlueColor()
    println("Blue!")
} else if (dot.name == "RedNode") {
    foundRedColor()
    println("Red!")
} else {
    println("Nooooo! This shouldn't happen")
}
```