# Swift: how to compare the first n digits past the decimal place for CGFloat?

Tags: swift, floating-point

How can you compare if A and B, both `CGFloats`, are equal up to 5 digits past the decimal place? This is necessary because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087625/skcolor-comparison-works-in-simulator-not-on-iphone-5s-and-with-standard-colors?noredirect=1#comment48290326_30087625).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The same as you would compare floating point numbers in any other language.

Take the absolute value of the difference of the numbers and compare it against your acceptable delta.

```
let delta: CGFloat = 0.00001

let a: CGFloat = 3.141592
let b: CGFloat = 3.141593


if abs(a-b) < delta {
    println("close enough for government work")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Going off the answer that @nhgrif gave, I created something pretty easy to use in an existing app that had some Double comparison bugs.

```
infix operator ~<=
infix operator ~==
infix operator ~>=

extension Double {

    static func ~<= (lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Bool {
        (lhs < rhs) || (lhs ~== rhs)
    }

    static func ~>= (lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Bool {
        (lhs > rhs) || (lhs ~== rhs)
    }

    static func ~== (lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Bool {
        abs(lhs - rhs) < 0.0000000001
    }
}
```

You can then just use it like any other comparator
`(1000.0 / 100.0) ~== 10.0 // true`